# Do original files stay frozen in Amazon Glacier when I restore them to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm using `s3cmd` and I want to restore some project files from Glacier and I'm just trying to understand what is happening to the files. As far as I see I get a temporary copy of the object restored to S3. What if I change or delete the restored object will the glacier object also be changed or deleted? And after X amount of days the objects will simply be just again glacier objects?

And a second question. When I restore files for 90 days but after 30 days I no longer need them can I remove them from s3 and keep the ones in glacier before the 90 days are over? Could I extend the 90 Days period ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/):

> You use S3’s new RESTORE operation to access an object archived in Glacier. As part of the request, you need to specify a retention period in days. Restoring an object will generally take 3 to 5 hours. Your restored object will remain in both Glacier and S3’s Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) for the duration of the retention period. At the end of the retention period the object’s data will be removed from S3; the object will remain in Glacier.

So your original object will remain in Glacier even if you change or delete the retrieved S3 copy, and then the S3 copy will be deleted after the retention period you specify.